# に usage in 「定めに抗う...」

Tags: particle-に

I am having trouble understanding the usage of に in this particular context. I've attached a picture of the sentence「定めに抗い、変革を望む者…」.[image] Here's another sentence where I think に is acting in the same way with 「今こそ、この世の歪みの深淵に立ち向かうがいい」. [image]

Comment: Hi - thanks for your first question on Japanese Language Stack Exchange! If you could edit your post to indicate your research effort (e.g. what you think に might mean in this context), then that would help other users to know how best to answer your question/clear up any confusion, as well as make this more than a translation question (which is strictly off-topic; see https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You're 100% correct that these two instances of に are being used to convey the same thing. In this case, they carry the same meaning as 〜に対して, which in these instances has a sense of "against (something)".

So:

> 定めに抗い、変革を望む者…
>   Those who go against the norms/rules, and wish for change...

and

> 今こそ、この世の歪みの深淵に立ち向かうがいい。
>   The time is now to confront the abyss of this world's distortedness.